# Why the backgroundworker cancel button dosent cancel the backgroundworker operation?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I added this two lines in the top of the Form1:

```
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true; 
backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

In the button click event start i added:

```
timer2.Enabled = true;
if (this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy == false)
            {
                this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
```

This is the DoWork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            if (worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }  
            if (filesContent.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < filesContent.Length; i++)
                {
                    File.Copy(filesContent[i], Path.Combine(contentDirectory, Path.GetFileName(filesContent[i])), true);
                }
            }
            WindowsUpdate();
            CreateDriversList();
            GetHostsFile();
            Processes();
        }
```

Then the work completed event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
            {
                this.Diagnose.Text = "THIS OPERATION HAS BEEN CANCELLED";
            }
            else if (!(e.Error == null))
            {
                this.Diagnose.Text = ("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                processfinish = true;
            }
        }
```

In the end the button click cancel event:

```
private void CancelOperation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();  
        }
```

When i click the cancel button i used a breakpoint i saw its going to the CancelAsync();
But then its just jumping to the timer2 tick event and keep working .
timer2 is starting to work once i clicked the start button.

This is the timer2 tick event:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timerCount += 1;
            TimerCount.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timerCount).ToString();
            TimerCount.Visible = true;
            if (processfinish == true)
            {
                timer2.Enabled = false;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }                           
        }
```

Why when i click the cancel button the operation is not stop and keep on going regular ?
And in the cancel button do i need to disposr/clean any objects or the backgroundworker somehow ?

This is what i did in the DoWork now:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (true)
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;  
                    if (filesContent.Length > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < filesContent.Length; i++)
                        {
                            File.Copy(filesContent[i], Path.Combine(contentDirectory, Path.GetFileName(filesContent[i])), true);
                        }
                    }
                    WindowsUpdate();
                    CreateDriversList();
                    GetHostsFile();
                    Processes();
                }
            }
        }
```

And the cancel button :

```
private void CancelOperation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            timer2.Enabled = false;
        }
```

But now in the DoWork i dont have the return;
So it never get to the completed event when i click the cancel button and never show the message this.Diagnose.Text = "THIS OPERATION HAS BEEN CANCELLED";

If i add now the return;
Then the rest of the code in the DoWork will be unreachable code

What to do then ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your `DoWork` event checks the `CancellationPending` property *before* it starts doing all the heavy work.

The correct way is to check this property *inside* the loop.

Also note that if you're copying just a few, but very very large files, and want to cancel even while it is busy copying a file, you need to write out code that can be cancelled that does the copying as well.

Comment: Im using a loop now but still its not good. Updated my question with what i did.

Comment: The cancel is not only for the copy files loop it should cancel the whole operation also if its in the middle of the other functions in the DoWork event. so i used While(true) loop

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the CancellationPending at the wrong stage.

Try something like ;

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        if (filesContent.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < filesContent.Length; i++)
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                   e.Cancel = true;
                   return;
                }  
                File.Copy(filesContent[i], Path.Combine(contentDirectory, Path.GetFileName(filesContent[i])), true);
            }
        }

        if (!worker.CancellationPending)
            WindowsUpdate();

        if (!worker.CancellationPending)
           CreateDriversList();

        if (!worker.CancellationPending)
           GetHostsFile();

        if (!worker.CancellationPending)
           Processes();

        if (worker.CancellationPending)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```